Collect URLs from list in R using a for loop
I have a list of URLs collected from Twitter. All of the URL are shortened (like bit.ly, buff.ly, etc.), and I need the full link with the domain name for some analysis I'll be doing down the road. Since there's several thousands URLs I want to automate the process, and are trying to write a for loop for this.
I started with just writing a simple for loop using httr:HEAD, which works fine as long as the link is valid.
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

# Creating an example with the first few links in my data
shortened_urls <- c("buff.ly/2uDuJw9", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", 
"buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39VDwcd", "buff.ly/2U8oyZW", "buff.ly/2IRrrJ7",
"buff.ly/3a00mQb", "buff.ly/3a83WHM") 

out_df <- data.frame() # empty df to store the results

for (i in 1:length(shortened_urls )) {
    x <- HEAD(shortened_urls[i])
    out_df <- bind_rows(out_df, data.frame(x$url))
}


This gives the expected results with a dataframe containing the full links.
good dataframe with full links
However, since many of the links I want to collect are several years old, some of them are not valid anymore, which causes an error in the loop and it stops at the eight URL. I want the loop to simply ignore those links, and continue on.
I tried adding an argument to the loop that checks if the link is still valid, and if it's not skip to the next url.
for (i in 1:length(shortened_urls )) {
  valid_url <- TRUE
  while(valid_url){
    x <- HEAD(shortened_urls[i])
    out_df <- bind_rows(out_df, data.frame(x$url))
  valid_url <- httr::GET(shortened_urls[i])$status_code == "200"
  if(!valid_url) {
    next
  }
  }
}

However, this causes an issue where the loop gets stuck at the fifth link, and just keeps writing this link over and over again, never going to the sixth link or exiting the loop:
Weird dataframe
The problem persist even if I try simply removing the URL in question, it'll just keep iterating over the next URL instead.

Welcome to SO!  Whilst not directly relevant to your question...  Growing objects in a loop is highly inefficient.  See, fopr example, Chapter 3 of The R Inferno.  One way to avoid this is to convert your code to use a member of the *apply family and then bind the results together.

You never increment i inside your while.  Hence the infinite loop.

@Limey thank you! That's of course what was missing (and I'll be sure to take a look at apply as an alternative to the loop).

Something like this?
tryCatch will catch errors that can be tested afterwards
library(httr)

# Creating an example with the first few links in my data
shortened_urls <- c("buff.ly/2uDuJw9", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", 
                    "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39VDwcd", "buff.ly/2U8oyZW", "buff.ly/2IRrrJ7",
                    "buff.ly/3a00mQb", "buff.ly/3a83WHM") 

# Create an empty list to store the results
out_urls <- character(length(shortened_urls)) |> as.list()
for (i in seq_along(shortened_urls )) {
  x <- tryCatch(
    HEAD(shortened_urls[i]),
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if(inherits(x, "error")) {
    out_urls[[i]] <- x
  } else if(status_code(x) %/% 100 == 2) {
      out_urls[[i]] <- x[["url"]]
  } else out_urls[[i]] <- sprintf("error: %d", status_code(x))
}

ok <- !sapply(out_urls, inherits, "error")
out_df <- data.frame(url = unlist(out_urls[ok]))


Edit
And here is a lapply loop version of the code above.
out_urls <- lapply(shortened_urls, \(x) {
  h <- tryCatch(
    HEAD(x),
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if(inherits(h, "error")) {
    h
  } else if(status_code(h) %/% 100 == 2) {
    h[["url"]]
  } else sprintf("error: %d", status_code(h))
})

ok <- !sapply(out_urls, inherits, "error")
out_df <- data.frame(url = unlist(out_urls[ok]))


If you need target URL values but do not care if those are still accessible, you could disable redirection, send requests only towards link shorteners and extract targets from headers.
I'm using httr2 instead of httr here, mostly because of convenience, but this is also a problem where one might benefit from httr2::req_perform_parallel() -- url shortening services should generally not have issues with high request rates, though be prepared to split your whole list into smaller chunks if they start to block you. Or switch to req_perform_sequential() as this can slowed down with req_throttle()
Cases where short urls themselves cause issues (e.g. shortener service itself is not available anymore, record is removed or there are just malformed urls) can be handled by wrapping resp_header() with purrr::possibly(), instead of an error it now returns some default value, like NA.
library(httr2)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

# add one faulty url
shortened_urls <- c("here-be/error", "buff.ly/2uDuJw9", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", 
                    "buff.ly/39zvF3Y", "buff.ly/39VDwcd", "buff.ly/2U8oyZW", "buff.ly/2IRrrJ7",
                    "buff.ly/3a00mQb", "buff.ly/3a83WHM") 

# get target for a single shorturl with httr2
# (disable redirection, extract Location from response header)
request(shortened_urls[2]) |>
  req_options(followlocation = FALSE) |>
  req_perform() |>
  resp_header("Location")
#> [1] "https://www.uib.no/aktuelt/134112/tips-og-r%C3%A5d-i-forbindelse-med-koronavirusutbruddet"

# apply that same logic to all shorturls:
# * generate a list of requests
# * apply req_options() on all list items to disable redirection
# * pass requests to req_perform_parallel(), 
#   redirection is disabled and shorturl services *should* not have issues with 
#   parallel requests, though be prepared to split your shorturl list 
#   into smaller batches; on_error = "continue" keeps it going
# * extract Location from all responses, possibly() adds default value (NA) 
#   if resp_header() happens to fail
redirect_urls <- 
  shortened_urls |>
  map(request) |>
  map(req_options, followlocation = FALSE) |>
  req_perform_parallel(on_error = "continue") |> 
  map_chr(possibly(resp_header,otherwise = NA), "Location")

Result:
tibble(shorturl = shortened_urls,
       redir = redirect_urls)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    shorturl        redir                                                        
#>    <chr>           <chr>                                                        
#>  1 here-be/error   <NA>                                                         
#>  2 buff.ly/2uDuJw9 https://www.uib.no/aktuelt/134112/tips-og-r%C3%A5d-i-forbind…
#>  3 buff.ly/39zvF3Y https://www.uib.no/korona                                    
#>  4 buff.ly/39zvF3Y https://www.uib.no/korona                                    
#>  5 buff.ly/39zvF3Y https://www.uib.no/korona                                    
#>  6 buff.ly/39VDwcd https://www.fvn.no/mening/kronikk/i/OpAeEO/hvordan-stopper-v…
#>  7 buff.ly/2U8oyZW https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2020/03/coronavir…
#>  8 buff.ly/2IRrrJ7 https://psykologisk.no/2020/03/hvordan-kan-vi-mote-barns-fry…
#>  9 buff.ly/3a00mQb https://www.dagsavisen.no/oslo/hjemmeskole-og-korona-foreldr…
#> 10 buff.ly/3a83WHM https://underdog24.no/bogg/ep-08-norges-raeste-prepper-er-fo…

httr2 also provides few tools to work with lists of responses, so if you are just after successful requests, you can do something like
  ... |>
  resps_successes() |>
  resps_data(\(resp) resp_header(resp, "Location"))

